# Converting data from New York State Court data into Data Frame to be visualized R (importing but not becoming proper data frame)

Tags: r, shinyapps

I am trying to important data automatically from the data set on this website: https://ww2.nycourts.gov/oca-stat-act-31371. When I import this data, it imports into R just fine into a data frame but when I try to visualize it, the visuals are completely messed up. Similarly, when I try to run it in an R Shiny App it gives me the error input string 1 is invalid UTF-8. What do I do?

Below is the code to import and wrangle the data:

```
NYSdata <- read.csv("https://www.nycourts.gov/LegacyPDFS/court-research/OCA-STAT-Act.csv")

new <- c("row_num", "court_type", "region", "district", "county", "court", "arresting_agency", "arrest_type", "arraign_year", "arraign_month", "top_charge_at_arraignment", "severity", "weight", "law", "article_section", "attempt_flag", "gender", "ethnicity", "race", "arrest_age", "docket_status", "disposition_type", "disposition_detail", "dismissal_reason", "most_severe_sentence", "fines_imposed", "fees_imposed", "surcharges_imposed")

names(NYSdata) <- new

NYSdata <- select(NYSdata, -c("row_num"))
```

Here is the code to visualize the data:

```
NYSdata %>% 


ggplot(aes(x = race)) + 
geom_bar() + 
xlab("Court") + 
ylab("Number of People") + 
abs(title = "Racial Breakdown of New York State Courts") + 
theme_economist() + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust = -.3)
```

Here is what I get when I run the above code:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The csv file is relatively large (~50Mb) and the download speed from the website is relatively slow, so you are potentially hitting the "timeout" limit. Try changing the timeout and see if you end up with an uncorrupted data file, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
options(timeout = 1200)
NYSdata <- read.csv("https://www.nycourts.gov/LegacyPDFS/court-research/OCA-STAT-Act.csv")
new <- c("row_num", "court_type", "region", "district", "county", "court", "arresting_agency", "arrest_type", "arraign_year", "arraign_month", "top_charge_at_arraignment", "severity", "weight", "law", "article_section", "attempt_flag", "gender", "ethnicity", "race", "arrest_age", "docket_status", "disposition_type", "disposition_detail", "dismissal_reason", "most_severe_sentence", "fines_imposed", "fees_imposed", "surcharges_imposed")
names(NYSdata) <- new
NYSdata <- select(NYSdata, -c("row_num"))
NYSdata %>%
ggplot(aes(x = race)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  xlab("Court") + 
  ylab("Number of People") + 
  abs(title = "Racial Breakdown of New York State Courts") + 
  theme_economist() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust = -.3)
```

### Edit

A better option would be to use the vroom package, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vroom)
library(ggthemes)
options(timeout = 2400)
NYSdata <- vroom("https://www.nycourts.gov/LegacyPDFS/court-research/OCA-STAT-Act.csv")
new <- c("row_num", "court_type", "region", "district", "county", "court", "arresting_agency", "arrest_type", "arraign_year", "arraign_month", "top_charge_at_arraignment", "severity", "weight", "law", "article_section", "attempt_flag", "gender", "ethnicity", "race", "arrest_age", "docket_status", "disposition_type", "disposition_detail", "dismissal_reason", "most_severe_sentence", "fines_imposed", "fees_imposed", "surcharges_imposed")
names(NYSdata) <- new
NYSdata <- select(NYSdata, -c("row_num"))
NYSdata %>%
  filter(grepl("[[:alpha:]]+", x = race)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = race)) +
  geom_bar() +
  xlab("Court") + 
  ylab("Number of People") + 
  labs(title = "Racial Breakdown of New York State Courts") + 
  theme_economist() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust = -.3)
```

[image: example_1.png]

(Also, I filtered out the small number of patients that have a numeric code for race instead of a word, using `filter(grepl("[[:alpha:]]+", x = race))`, but you might not want to do that depending on your use-case)

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed the problem of at least importing the uncorrupted data file. I will now ask another question to see how to fix the problem with the shiny app.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an encoding issue. I re-saved the .csv on my macbook using "CSV UTF-8" and it worked fine when loading and plotting. I tried doing the encoding in R, but still did not work properly:

```
NYSdata <- read.csv("OCA-STAT-Act.csv") %>% 
           dplyr::mutate_if(is.character, utf8_encode) 
    
# Also, trying encoding when reading in the csv.
NYSdata <- read.csv("OCA-STAT-Act.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

This code gives you closer to what you want, but still outputs a strange figure (lots of text at the bottom of the bar graph).

[image: Plot after assigning UTF-8 encoding in R]

Using `read_csv` seems to resolve this issue without having to specify.

```
library(readr)

NYSdata <- read_csv("OCA-STAT-Act.csv")
```

[image: Plot after using read_csv]

There are many Stack Overflow entries on UTF-8 encoding. Here is one for handling it with the Shiny app: [input string 1 is invalid UTF-8 Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62541535/input-string-1-is-invalid-utf-8-shiny-app)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this with me. Here is a link to a new question I asked specifically about the Shiny App: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012667/running-r-shiny-app-and-getting-error-input-string-1-is-invalid-utf-8-when-imp